# Flask relationship model multiple get or create if not exist

Tags: python, many-to-many, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert, flask

I just started with Flask and SQLAlchemy in flask.

So I have a many-to-many relationship using the example here  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html
If you scrolldown to the part about Keywords and tags this is what I am working on.
So far I am able to insert new Keywords related to my Post and I am using append. Which is wrong I know. So what happens is that the next time a non unique keyword occurs in a blog post it will throw an error about Conflict with Keyword (since keywords are supposed to be unique)

I know the right way is something else, I just don't know what. I have seen an example of 
get_or_create(keyword) which basically filters by keyword and then adds it if not found. However I believe as data size grows this will also be wrong. (Several calls on every save with single insert). I love the way SQLAlchemy is doing multiple insert automatically. I wish to keep that but avoid this duplicate key issue.

Edit: found the solution, SQLAlchemy docs guide you towards error but the explanation is in there. I have added the answer.

Comment: btw I am using append for related model. like this. post.keywords.append(Keyword("foo")) then calling commit.

Comment: Could you post your models and add some real code?

Comment: I updated the post. I have tried stuff like merge() which obviously wont do anything and does nothing. A second page load will always cause the error. I want to only add the games (tags) that don't exist to the Game table and to the usergames (if not exist). Ofcourse I cant have a game that is in usergames but not it Game. that part no problem. I get duplicate error for Game()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after hours of trial and error I found the solution, plus somethings I was doing wrong.

This is how SQL alchemy works. the answer is merge.

make a LIST of tags as Tag models, don;t matter if they exist as long as your primary key is name or something unique.

```
tags = [Tag('a1'),Tag('a2')]
```

Say you have Tag a1 already in DB but we don't really care. All we want is to insert if related data does not exist. WHich is what SQLalchemy does.
Now you make a Post with the LIST of ALL the tags we made. If its one only , it also is a list.

therefore

```
new_post = Post('a great new post',post_tags=tags)
db.session.merge(new_post)
db.session.commit()
```

I have used Flask syntax but the idea is same. Just make sure you are not creating the Model OUTSIDE the session. More likely, you wont do it.

This was actually simple but nowhere in the SQLAlchemy docs this example is mentioned. They use append() which is wrong. It's only to create new Tags knowing you are not making duplicates.

Hope it helps.

Comment: merge() would only be appropriate if the Tag() had as its primary key the string content "a1", "a2", i.e. a natural primary key - because merge() only deals with primary keys.  A more generic "object unique on X" recipe is at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject - this is more or less outside of the scope of the tutorial.   the usage of "append()" in the tutorial isn't "wrong", it's illustrating how many-to-many relationships work.   merge() wouldn't work in the tutorial example either since the Keyword has a surrogate pk.